# jquery Datatable - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I am having the following error around undefined (reading 'length') on Jquery Datatable.

I am generating the table dynamically.

```
table#myTable.table.is-fullwidth
            thead
                tr
                    each column in tableColumns
                        th
                            p #{column}   
            tbody
                each row in tableResults
                    tr
                    each data in row
                        td
                            p #{data}
```

and call the javascript as such.

```
 script.
        $(function() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
```

I am trying to get some pagination and sorting function into the html table.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: your snippet is not clear. from this I am assuming that, you should wait for your data to be fetched, get it rendered on UI, and then call the javascript . proper sequence will make it work

Comment: To add more context, tableColumns & tableResults comes from backend.  So I will loop over it and display

$(function()) -> short hand for document.ready(), will load the DataTable after the DOM is loaded.

By proper sequence, does the above make sense? do i need to change anything?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize the DataTable plugin after the document is fully loaded

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: $(function()) is already for document.ready, its a short hand for it

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue for this. Basically the DOM is not in the right format, for anyone else who is struggling with this error:

- Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (HTML DOM sourced)
- dataTables.min.js:37

Please check your HTML DOM. Hope this helps someone else who come across this.

Below is my update version of the HTML to be render, i had to provide more indent to the following line: This is written in PUG / Jade.

```
each data in row
```

```
table#myTable.table.is-fullwidth
            thead
                each column in tableColumns
                    th #{column}   
            tbody
                each row in tableResults
                    tr
                        each data in row
                            td #{data}
```